# How to convert the Object[] to String[] in Java?

Tags: java, string, object

I have a question about Java. I have an `Object[]` (Java default, not the user-defined) and I want to convert it to a `String[]`. Can anyone help me? thank you.

Comment: Where does this Object[] come from?

Comment: @RickyClarkson Thanks Rick, it's a good point to avoid redundant boxing unboxing.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

this is conversion

```
for(int i = 0 ; i < objectArr.length ; i ++){  
   try {
      strArr[i] = objectArr[i].toString();
   } catch (NullPointerException ex) {
       // do some default initialization
   }
}
```

This is casting

```
String [] strArr = (String[]) objectArr;  //this will give you class cast exception
```

**Update:**

**Tweak 1**

```
 String[] stringArray = Arrays.copyOf(objectArray, objectArray.length, String[].class);
```

**Tweak2**

```
 Arrays.asList(Object_Array).toArray(new String[Object_Array.length]);
```

**Note**:That only works if the objects are all Strings; his current code works even if they are not

forTweak1 :only on Java 1.6 and above

Comment: Having `Object` as an identifier seems like a bad idea, and the casting you suggests result in a `ClassCastException`.

Comment: This doesn't work: String [] strArr = (String[]) objectArr[];

Comment: Another issue: if the object array happens to contain null, you'll get an NPE with this solution. Better to go through **String.valueOf** as I do in my answer.

Comment: String [] strArr = (String[]) objectArr; this still won't work!

Comment: (Unless the objectArr is in fact a String-array, but I doubt it is)

Comment: Well sure, but an `Object[]` variable could contain a `String[]`. Try for instance `Object[] objs = new String[] { "hello", "world" };` (Though, as I said, I doubt that this is the case here.)

Comment: aiobe: I try this: Object[] objs = new String[] { "hello", "world" }; strArr = (String[]) objectArr;  Still CCE

Comment: nanda: it should be `(String[]) objs` in the end :-)

Comment: @nanda Yes you are correct it will give you classcastexception @ runtime as we are not sure what object is holding

Comment: @org.life.java, but both "tweaks" will give an ArrayStoreException if you have anything but strings in the object array though.

Comment: it should be (String[]) objs in the end :-) :-/ can you write a code where String[] strArr = (String[]) objectArr; doesn't throw any exception?

Comment: @nanda: `Object[] objs = new String[] { "hello", "world" }; String[] strArr = (String[]) objs;`

Answer (score 5):

Simply casting like this `String[] strings = (String[]) objectArray;` probably won't work.

Try something like this:

```
public static String[] asStrings(Object... objArray) {
    String[] strArray = new String[objArray.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < objArray.length; i++)
        strArray[i] = String.valueOf(objArray[i]);
    return strArray;
}
```

You could then use the function either like this

```
Object[] objs = { "hello world", -1.0, 5 };
String[] strings = asStrings(objs);
```

or like this

```
String[] strings = asStrings("hello world", -1.0, 5);
```

Comment: It won't handle NPE, with an array this could be often the case.

Comment: Ops. It should be `String.valueOf` (had it in an earlier revision :-) corrected. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Java 8 solution:

```
String[] strArr = Arrays.stream(objArr).map(Object::toString).toArray(String[]::new);
```

Answer (score 2):

I think this is the simplest way if all entries in objectArr are String:

```
for(int i = 0 ; i < objectArr.length ; i ++){
    strArr[i] = (String) objectArr[i];
}
```

Comment: gives a class cast exception if you have anything but strings in the object array...

Comment: not if you following my instructions :) : I think this is the simplest way *if all entries in objectArr are String*:

Answer (score 2):

I guess you could also use [System.arraycopy](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/System.html)

```
System.arraycopy(objarray, 0, strarray, 0, objarray.length);
```

provided, `strarray` is of the length `objarray.length` and objarray contain only strings. Or it would throw ArrayStoreException. See aioobe's comment.

Comment: ...and provided objarray contains only strings... otherwise you'll run into an ArrayStoreException.

Answer (score 0):

My point is not fit for the answer exactly (scenario specific), but it may happen someone unknowingly ended upon in object[].

in my case I was trying to convert List to String[] & on using .toArray() on list, it converted it to Object[]

So, specific to the mentioned scenario, a one-line solution

```
List<String> list = Arrays.asList("a", "b", "c", "d");
String[] array = list.toArray(new String[list.size()]);
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array)); // [a, b, c, d]
```

Answer (score 0):

The argument `toArray` is just a placeholder for the type so you do not need to allocate a certain size.

Using the following line will do just fine:

```
String[] array = list.toArray(new String[0]);
```

Here is another variation of the above line:

```
String [] strArr = Arrays.asList(Object_Array).toArray(new String[0]);
```